# Commands before deps in tox

Tags: python, tox

Is there a way to run a command before deps in tox. Here is the outline of what I want:

```
[testenv:local_code]
commands = 
    bash -c "if [ -d "{toxinidir}/tools" ]; then \
       git clone git+ssh://git@repo/tools.git {toxinidir}/tools; \
       fi"
deps =
    --editable=file:///{toxinidir}/tools
```

Unfortunately, deps run before commands (which I intuitively understand why). I was wondering if anyone knows a way around that

Answer (score 1):

You can simply move the installation of your dependencies into the `deps=` parameter where each of the commands gets executed sequentially.

Related information also in [Install-time dependencies in requirements.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36574463/install-time-dependencies-in-requirements-txt/36577310#36577310)