# pip --editable gets overwritten regardless of the order

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, dependencies, pypi

I have the following contents in my `tox.ini` file:

```
...
[testenv]
usedevelop = True
deps =
    --editable=file:///{toxinidir}/../some_dep
    --requirement=requirements.txt
...
```

now `requirements.txt` looks like this:

```
...
some_dep>=0.1.2
```

When `tox` creates a virtualenv it says:

```
py3-env create: /Users/someuser/PycharmProjects/some_project/.tox/py3-env
py3-env installdeps: --requirement=requirements.txt, --editable=file:////Users/someuser/PycharmProjects/some_project/../some_dep
```

And of course `/Users/someuser/PycharmProjects/some_project/../some_dep` exists.

Now the problem is, that I would expect to find an `egg-link` pointing to `/Users/someuser/PycharmProjects/some_project/../some_dep` but instead `some_dep` package gets installed from PyPI.

It seems that `--editable` was ignored or overwritten by contents of `requirements.txt`.

If I remove `some_dep` from `requirements.txt` I'm getting an expected behaviour: `egg-link` is present and everything works as expected but I can't modify my `requirements.txt` as this would complicate my deployment.

If I change ordering of `--editable` and `--requirement` lines in my `tox.ini` nothing changes: `some_dep` gets still installed from PyPI.

Is that an expected bahaviour? Is there something I can do to get my `--editable` parameter respected?

I'm using:

`pip 9.0.3 from /Users/mnowotka/PycharmProjects/ygo-public-apis/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tox is concatenating what you define in deps and passes it through to pip (executed as one command), so the outcome is controlled by pip. pip does not guarantee the ordering of installations as passed on the command line, so this is why it is the way it is.

Having said that: if you install the `requirements.txt` defining a higher versioned package (a real version should always be higher than the development version of a local dev install from source) after your editable install it is to be expected that it gets upgraded. If you want to make sure that your lower versioned local package gets installed you can do it in tox like this:

```
[testenv]
deps = 
    # whatever you need where order does not matter
    --requirement=requirements.txt        
commands =
    pip install --upgrade --editable={toxinidir}/../some_dep
    # now do your actual testing ...
    pytest tests/unit
```

What is defined in deps does not follow a predictable order (as explained above). The commands executed after deps are installed are executed in order and can be used to fix/adjust anything before executing the actual tests.

Also see [this answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36577310/2626627).

Side note: there has been some [discussion on the tox issue tracker](https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues/42) if tox should handle this differently.